# Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other laravel google/apiclient

Tags: laravel, google-api-client, pageviews, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to access Google Analytics in order to get the page views of my site, but due to the update in GA4 I'm unable to access it through the client_secrets.json file. I'm getting this error:

```
"
"error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
        { "message": "Login Required.",
          "domain": "global",
          "reason": "required",
          "location": "Authorization",
          "locationType": "header"
        }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
        { 
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
          "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
          "domain": "googleapis.com",
          "metadata": {
              "service": "analyticsreporting.googleapis.com",
              "method": "google.analytics.reporting.v4.Reporting.GetReports"
            }
        }
    ]
}
}"
```

What do I have to do and how can I use the property id instead of the view id? I only need to get the page views of all my site pages.

---

**my php-v 7.3**

**laravel platform 7**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

1. Create google service account https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts-create
2. Download file auth json
3. Config laravel env GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path-to-file-auth

I hope I can help you